# One view from two tables with identical column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two tables that we need to merge into a singular view. Normally I'd individually select columns to avoid this issue, however in this case the two tables are a combined 800 columns.

The only identical columns are the identifier columns. Unfortunately these cannot be changed as they are used by a 3rd party tool to sync table

```
Table A
GUID
Name
Address
...

Table B
GUID
Cell
Fax
Home2
...
```

Are good examples, just assume each table has 400 odd columns.

Obviously the traditional

```
SELECT a.*, b.* from table_a a, table_b a where a.guid = b.guid
```

Fails miserably. Is there any easy way to create the view without having to list out 799 individual column names? I was thinking perhaps a one off function to create the view but so far I'm hitting a wall.

Comment: Did you consider to generate the SQL script with column aliases in it?

Comment: Why can't you list the columns? And why do you have 400 columns in two tables??? That sounds like something is horribly wrong. And a view with 800 columns? What are you going to do with that? Regardless you do NOT want to use select * in a view. It causes all sorts of problems when the tables change. And you really should start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been available for more than 25 years now.

Comment: You can create the query dynamically, so you won't have to do the typing yourself. But Sean is right.

Comment: Preaching to the choir but this is a situation of business override because of a 3rd party system. I cannot get into details due to NDA reasons but suffice to say I'm not thrilled about it either. That being said I didn't think about ANSI-92 vs 89. Will likely tweak that bit. Worst comes to worst I'll just generate the join from a quick script

Comment: Right click on table in Management Studio, script table as SELECT TO.. on both tables. Ctrl+A -> Ctrl+C this scripts into new file. Profit!

Comment: Just use SSMS to generate your list painlessly. In object explorer expand your table until you get the "Columns" folder. Then select the folder and drag it to a query window. It will generate a list of every column already with commas ready to go. Then use replace to each comma with a comma and your alias. Voila! Rinse and Repeat for each table.

Comment: Script tables as SELECT TO and then add aliases using find/replace for one or both tables

Comment: I feel OP's pain though. Sounds like a medical system I worked with for a client. Each field was "GenericText01" or "GenericInt02". Hundreds of them. Then they masked them on the presentation layer. Every day they sent out a new mapping document. It was genuinely the worst database I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql as a solution.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (id INT, col1 NVARCHAR(50), col2 NVARCHAR(50))
GO
CREATE TABLE test2(id INT, col1 NVARCHAR(50), col2 NVARCHAR(50))
GO


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''

; WITH cte AS  (
SELECT 
CASE WHEN TABLE_NAME = 'test1' THEN TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS ' + + COLUMN_NAME +  't1' ELSE TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS ' + + COLUMN_NAME +  't2' END  AS a, 1 AS ID
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('test1', 'test2')
) 

SELECT @sql = 
'CREATE VIEW myview as 
select ' + (
SELECT
STUFF(
(
SELECT ', '+ [A]
FROM cte
WHERE ID = results.ID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
,1,2,''
) AS NameValues
FROM cte results
GROUP BY ID
) + ' from test1 join test2 on test1.id = test2.id' 

PRINT @sql
--EXEC (@sql)
```

The result is

```
CREATE VIEW myview
AS
    SELECT  test1.id AS idt1 ,
            test1.col1 AS col1t1 ,
            test1.col2 AS col2t1 ,
            test2.id AS idt2 ,
            test2.col1 AS col1t2 ,
            test2.col2 AS col2t2
    FROM    test1
            JOIN test2 ON test1.id = test2.id
```